# Brushed DC Motor Closed Loop Speed Control Under Load

Tags: motor, dc-motor, pid-controller, controller, rpm

I've designed a PI controller to control brushed DC motor speed between 0.6Hz - 6Hz (RPM:36 - 360). When I control the motor speed at 0.6Hz (approximately 4.0V supply and 60% PWM duty), it can rotate at target speed as I expected. But for this target speed (0.6Hz), when I apply a very small load, I can easily stop the dc motor (I think because of the low power, undervoltage etc.).
How can I solve this problem or increase torque for 0.6 Hz target speed?
[image: Motor]

Comment: To make significantly more torque at lower speed you probably need to increase the gear ratio and run the motor at higher voltage and higher shaft speed. However if the torque and current only need to increase a slight amount then perhaps the problem is that there is not sufficient resolution in the feedback measurement of 0.6 hz speed? How many pulses per rotation does your speed sensor indicate? Or else how are you measuring the speed as 0.6 hz?

Comment: It's the nature of the beast. You can't run motors arbitrarily slow if you do not have control over the commutation which you do not in a brushed motor. Even when you have that control it is tricky.

Comment: @SystemTheory I'm measuring 0.6hz with rotary position sensor and 20ms control loops.
https://tr.farnell.com/murata/sv01a103aea01r00/rotary-position-sensor-10k-5vdc/dp/2707456

Comment: @DKNguyen So what do you suggest?

Comment: @Gkhan Gearbox is the typical solution. You could also try adding current into the feedback loop to try and maintain torque without stalling the motor. But the motor is probably going to run very rough if it does run since you have no control over the commutation.

Comment: @DKNguyen But if I change the gearbox, then I can't drive the motor at 6hz.

Comment: _"when I apply a **very small** load, I can easily stop the dc motor(I think because of the low power, undervoltage etc.)"_ - It should produce ~4kg/cm at stall on 4V. Exactly how much torque is required to stop it? What voltage did you measure at the motor when stalled?

Comment: You're trying to measure rpm with a potentiometer???

Comment: @BruceAbbott Yes, with potentiometer. I have a mechanical design for this.

Comment: How do you measure rpm with it? Why not use a shaft encoder or tachometer?  What motor controller are you using? Can you show us the circuit?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but the info you have provided so far doesn't make much sense. With closed loop control the motor should go to full power if it can't rotate. That's ~4kg.cm at 4V, which is not what I would call 'very small'. Using a pot with 'a mechanical design' is a peculiar way to get rpm.

Comment: 60% PWM doesn't give the loop much headroom before hitting 100% PWM and then stalling. You should be able to get the same speed with 8V and 30%, or 12V and 20% PWM, which will allow more torque before stall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that *feed-forward* compensation works well for brushed motors. It can maintain fairly constant speed, even at slow RPM.

From your motor specs, stall current is 17A, with 12V supply. This spec suggests that winding resistance plus brush resistance is \$ 12V\over 17A\$ or 0.7 ohms. A compensating resistance of -0.7 ohms is required for feed-forward compensation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPR3RR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The negative resistance is generated by sensing motor current with a current-sampling resistor, which generates a small voltage which you amplify. For every amp sensed, you would **add** to the DC supply 1.4 V.
This method is also applicable to PWM.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that feed-forward. but yes it does work well.

Comment: @Jasen Perhaps not feed-forward, but I wish to distinguish it from conventional *feed-back*. It is possible to over-compensate with too much gain. In that case, more mechanical loading *increases* motor RPM.

Comment: @glen_geek Thank you for your answer. I will try this suggestion.

Comment: What does the negative resistance effectively do?

Comment: @DKNguyen Consider the simple motor model of a **BEMF voltage source** in series with a **resistance** (wire + brushes). BEMF voltage is proportional to RPM. When you add an external negative resistance, BEMF follows the driving voltage source more closely. If the external source is constant-voltage, so is RPM. This is true because resistance between two voltage sources approaches zero.

Comment: @glen_geek Oh, I see. The neg resistance removes/compensates for the current dependent voltage drop which reduces the supply voltage that gets to the BEMF and causes the motor to slow as it loads up.

Comment: This article describes simulation of negative resistance to charge a battery at constant voltage: https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21802103/generating-negative-resistance.